# QMake - Erratic behaviour When using echo System Command

Tags: qt, qmake

Using QMake, I read some boiler plate code, make modifications and write the modified code to a file.
However, I get very strange results. I have simplified the problem down to the following:

```
# Open boiler plate file
interfaceBoilerPlateCode = $$cat($$boilerPlateFile, blob)

# Make sure we read the right content
message("Content read: $$interfaceBoilerPlateCode")

# Write the read text into a file
output = $$system(echo $$interfaceBoilerPlateCode >> $$targetFile) # Doesnt work
output = $$system(echo "Howde" >> $$targetFile) # This works
```

The file being read is a plain text file containing only the string "Howde".
The contents of the file get read correctly.

However, when I try and write the contents of the file to another target file, I get no output (literally: no errors/warnings but no new file generated). However, if I use echo with just a string defined in the code itself (as in the last line of snippet above), a new file gets generated with the string "Howde" inside it.

What is going on? What am I doing wrong that the penultimate line does not generate a new file?

Comment: Does `$$interfaceBoilerPlateCode` need to be in double quotes for the `echo` command?

Comment: Tried that already. No effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use write_file. Instead of:

```
$$system(echo $$content >> $$file_path)
```

use

```
write_file($$file_path, $$content)
```